# React Javascript onclick outside div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, hide

[image: logout with svg icon]

I am working on a website and currently i am having an svg icon for logout. 
when icon is clicked an overlay is popped up with signout option. when user clicks on signout it should do certain operation and when user clicks outside div overlay should be hidden. i am failing to achieve this.

i tried to give focus to div by using tabIndex but then signout option is not clickable anymore.

Header.js

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    class MainHeader extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          logOutShown: false
        };
      }
    render() {
    var guiResult = [];
    if (this.state.logOutShown) {
      guiResult.push(
        <div className="Login__Overlay__Frame">
          <div className="User__Login__Overlay">
          <div className="Login__Content" tabIndex="1" onFocus={this.alerting.bind(this)} onBlur={this.toggleOverlay.bind(this)}>Signout</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
            <div className="Header__Icon">
              <div className="Icons__Log__In" tabIndex="0" onClick={this.validate.bind(this)} onBlur={this.toggleOverlay.bind(this)}/>
              {guiResult}
            </div>
    );
  }

  toggleOverlay(){
    console.log("toggle overlay");
    this.setState({ logOutShown: false});
  }

  validate() {
    console.log("validate:");
    this.setState(
      {
        logOutShown: true
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can add handlers to overlay `<div className="User__Login__Overlay" onClick={this.toggleOverlay.bind(this)}>`

Comment: You can check the click on overlay, but there is a problem!!.  When you click anything inside the overlay, it will pick that up too.  What I tend to do is create a component for doing the overlay, and inside the overlay there is a container, and this container attaches to the onClick and calls `event.stopPropagation()`.  This will then stop click's on your content firing the event on the overlay.

Comment: @Keith i shall give it a try now by creating a new component for overlay. may be can you provide me overall structure of the new component will look like as i got confused in this "and inside the overlay there is a container, and this container attaches to the onClick and calls event.stopPropagation()"

Comment: @Kirill as Keith mentioned it didnt work.

Comment: I'll see if I can knock up a quick snippet.  give us 10..

Comment: @Keith solution's rocks! best one by far. thanks @Keith!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example, I'm using React hooks here instead of classes, but you can use classes too..

The main part is the onClick on the container div, if you run the example below and click on the dialog it won't close it, but clicking on the overlay will.

The `e.stopPropagation()` on the container div is what stops the events on the contents firing the events on the overlay.  Instead of using `stopPropagation`, another option is checking the `target` & `currentTarget` inside the overlay onClick..

```js
const {useState} = React;


function Overlay(props) {
  const {contents} = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  if (open) {
    return <div className="overlay" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
      <div onClick={(e) => {
        //stop clicks getting to the overlay
        e.stopPropagation();
      }}className="overlay-container">
        {contents()}
      </div>
    </div>
  }
  return null;
}


ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  This is some content to overlay.<br/>
  for testing..
  <Overlay contents={() =>
    <div>This is the contents, clicking here wont effect ovelay</div>
  }/>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.overlay-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a well writen library like this one: [react-outside-click-handler](https://github.com/airbnb/react-outside-click-handler)

example:

```
import OutsideClickHandler from 'react-outside-click-handler';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <OutsideClickHandler
      onOutsideClick={() => {
        alert('You clicked outside of this component!!!');
      }}
    >
      Hello World
    </OutsideClickHandler>
  );
}
```

Edit:

As I am editing this comment today, a lot of new library bring this feature to your code.

If you use a components library check if an util exists in it. ([chakra](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/utility-hooks/use-outside-click), [mantine](https://mantine.dev/hooks/use-click-outside/), [material-ui](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-click-away-listener/)).

Other solution exists inside hooks libraries like [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useClickAway.md).

Answer (score 4):

Use react refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

You check for the `target` of the event and use that to `show/hide` the signout button.

add event listener when component is mounted.

```
componentWillMount() { document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside, false); }
```

remove event listener when component is mounted.

```
componentWillUnmount() { document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside, false); }
```

do the check for the outside click something like this

```
handleClickOutside(e) {
    if(this.submitPopoverRef.contains(e.target)) {
        // the click happened in the component
        // code to handle the submit button
        // submit();
        return;
    } 

    // click happened outside the component
    // hide the popover
    this.handleClick(); // set the state false
}

<div ref={node => this.submitPopoverRef = node}> 
... Your code here...

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @keith's answer:
Using React hooks as well as classes: 
Assuming a parent and child divs, where you'd like the parent div to handle the click ONLY when the click was not inside the child div:

```js
const clickedParent = () => {};
const clickedChild = () => {};
```

```html
<div onClick={clickedParent}>
  <div className="selc-hd-so-remove" onClick={e=> { e.stopPropagation(); clickedChild(); }} > Child Div Clicked</div>
</div>
Parent Div Clicked
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `stopPropagation` on Child Elements

```js
export default function App() {
  const parentHandler = () => {
    console.log("Parent");
  };
  const childHandler = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Child");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={parentHandler}>
        <div onClick={childHandler}>Child Div</div>
        Parent Div
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```