# Prevent new EventListener from triggering for event that occurred just before the EventListener was added

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, stoppropagation

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#adding_a_listener_during_event_dispatch) explains:

> If an EventListener is added to an EventTarget while it is processing an event, that event does not trigger the listener. However, that same listener may be triggered during a later stage of event flow, such as the bubbling phase.

What are the ways to prevent this from happening?

Possible Solutions:

1. Call `event.stopPropagation()` when the event is invoked.

I'm not a fan of this solution because the solution is not localized near the problem. The solution is in where the click originates and the problem is the code that adds the new event listener.

2. Add the event listener inside of a setTimeout:`setTimeout(() => {element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler},0)`

This solution is cohesive: the problem of the new eventListener triggering immediately is solved right where the event listener is added.  Also it doesn't stop propagation for an event that other listeners might depend on.  However, it feels like a hack to wrap it inside a setTimeout like this.

Do better solutions exist to prevent the new event listener from firing immediately due to the click that caused the event listener to be added?

This problem occurred for me when attempting to make a popup appear that closes itself for a click outside.  Since the click that creates the popup is also a click outside.  The popup closes immediately.

[Link to example use-case including solutions](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-platform-qpr56?file=/src/Main.jsx)

Comment: `if (ev.target === <your popup>) { return; }`

Comment: `However, it feels like a hack`   It might feel like a hack, but because it's such a common approach for next tick, it 's maybe not as hacky as you think.  You could use PostMessage / flags etc, but to be honest it's probably not as clean and simple as a `setTimeout`

Comment: OK, I missed the last paragraph. I don't really see why you need to dynamically add event listeners. Can't you just use event delegation? Seems like just the thing - set it up once, don't have to keep changing the listeners all the time.

Comment: Just a tip on creating popups, what I normally do is create a semi-transparent div that the popup sits on, you then listen for clicks on this, and because the div is above the existing controls it wont receive any bubbled events.  I did something similar here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002313/react-javascript-onclick-outside-div/55003301#55003301

Comment: An overlay seems like the right approach

Comment: @VLAZ, In the example I have linked, I'm using react and the event listener is added on componentDidMount and removed on unmount so that it wont use up resources when it doesn't need to

Comment: @Jordan the example you have linked is not contained in your question. We require questions to be self-contained. One of the reasons that some users cannot follow the links. I cannot open codesandbox, for example. Nor do you even have a tag about React. I couldn't really guess that you didn't use vanilla JS.

Comment: @VLAZ Good point.  The setup code is rather large and I didn't want to post a huge block with the question.  I still feel that the question stands on it's own - the react implementation is just one way it can appear.  So I'm comfortable leaving the question as is.  The codesandbox example is just meant to be supplementary - but I can remove it if you feel like it reduces the quality of the question.